# Running Django test gives "psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation already exists" error

Tags: django, postgresql, django-tests

I restored a database from a text (sql) file:

```
psql ideatree < ideatree.sql
```

which works with no errors.

After running migrations I bring up the Django development server and the site comes up fine.

But when I run tests:

```
python manage.py test
```

I get the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "ideatree_colors" already exists
```

"ideatree_colors" is a table in the db, but test is creating its own separate test database, and indeed after this error the test database is left behind (I delete it before running tests again).

I completely dropped the cluster, re-installed Postgresql-13, restored the database, and ran migrations again.  Same error.

Comment: What happens if you drop the DB again and run migrations on a blank DB without restoring? You may have an error in your migrations that you don't get with a restored DB

Comment: @IainShelvington Interesting. After dropping the DB, then creating an empty DB by the same name and running migrations, the same 'psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable' error appears after the the migration: ' Applying ideatree.0002_colors' .  This is the development site.  Looking at production, the migrations differ, out of sync somehow.  So is it safe/advisable to reset migrations to initial on development?  What is best practice for managing migrations with git between devel and production?

Comment: I used the clear steps at https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html to reset migrations to an initial state, and it's working.  @IainShelvington If you'll write up your comment as an answer I'll accept it.